# Self-adjoint projections of a C*-algebra as complete lattices?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, order-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

In Blackadar's *Operator Algebras*, there is the following remark after the proposition II.3.3.1 :

> The projections in a C*-algebra do not form a lattice in general

In the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77182/c-algebras-as-banach-lattices), it is said that:

> If you restrict $\leq$ to the set of *self-adjoint projections* in $A$, you do get a lattice, which is isomorphic to the lattice of closed subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^2$.  The supremum of $a$ and $b$ in this lattice is $I$ and the infimum of $a$ and $b$ is $0$.

Does this statement really holds?
And if this is the case, can we also prove that it is a continuous lattice?

Recall that a continuous lattice is a complete lattice $L$ in which every element $y$ is equal to $\bigvee \{x \in D \mid x \ll y\}$ where $x \ll y$ ("x approximates y" or "x way below y") if for any directed set $D \subseteq P$, $y \leq \bigvee D$ implies that there is a $d \in D$ such that $x \leq d$

**EDIT**: Given Martin Argerami's answer, I'm now wondering if projections of an arbitrary von Neumann algebra form a continuous lattice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second statement is a statement about the algebra $M_2(\mathbb C)$. This is the von Neumann algebra $B(\mathbb C^2)$. The set of selfadjoints projections in a von Neumann algebra forms a lattice (a complete one: the union of projections is the projection onto the closure of the union of the ranges; and the meet of projections is the projection onto the intersection of the ranges).

Type I von Neumann algebras (finite-dimensional, in particular) have minimal projections, so the set of selfadjoint projections would be a continuous lattice in the sense you give. I'm not so sure for arbitrary von Neumann algebras.

For a general C$^*$-algebra (not von Neumann), the set of self-adjoint projections is usually not a lattice.

The set of selfadjoint elements of a von Neumann algebra does not form a lattice (even in the finite-dimensional case, as the example shows).

Comment: I posted a [more sharpened question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/133022/projections-in-a-w-algebra-as-a-continuous-lattice) on mathoverflow and according to the answer I had, it seems that projections of an arbitrary von Neumann algebra $A$ form a continuous lattice when $A$ is finite-dimensional, i.e. isomorphic to $B(\mathbb{C}^n)$ (Blackadar, III.1.5.12).

Comment: Nice, thanks. ${ }$